# Embedded inline text DOM in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Looking through some javascript source code from [khan/perseus](https://github.com/khan/perseus), I found the following, and I've never seen it before:

```
   return <span className="perseus-widget-expression">
           <input ref="input" type="text"
               value={this.props.currentValue}
               onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
               onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}
               onChange={this.handleChange} />
           <span className="output">
               <span className="tex"
                       style={{opacity: result.parsed ? 1.0 : 0.5}}>
                   <TeX>{this.state.lastParsedTex}</TeX>
               </span>
               <span className="placeholder">
                   <span ref="error" className="error"
                           style={{display: "none"}}>
                       <span className="buddy" />
                       <span className="message"><span>
                           {"Sorry, I don't understand that!"}
                       </span></span>
                   </span>
               </span>
           </span>
       </span>;
```

The file extension is "jsx", and I'm not sure if it gets processed on the server before being served, or if the browser actually interprets this as javascript. Is this a standard part of javascript, and if so what is it called?

Comment: You may find these links helpful: http://jsx.github.io/ and http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html